# Non computable numbers are normals?

Tags: real-numbers

We know that almost all real number are [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) and almost all real number are non computable. This does not suffice to deduce that all non computable numbers are normals but , intuitively (??) this seems reasonable. There is some proof ( or disproof) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disproof: The number with decimal expansion $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ is non-computable if and only if the number $0.a_18a_28a_38\dots$ is non-computable. But the second number is definitely not normal.

Comment: Any deeper reason why you changed $2\to 8$?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: No good reason. I was a bit worried about someone at first sight thinking I was doubling the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A\subset\mathbb N$ a non-recursive set. Then $\sum_{k\in A}10^{-k}$ uses only digits $0$ and $1$